# How to find the grid points of 2D matrix where the difference values are statistically significant at 95% significance level based on student's t-test

Tags: matlab, t-test, significance

I have calculated temperature difference between two model experiments. The difference is a 2D matrix (lon×lat). I want to find the grid points where the temperature differences are statistically significant at 95% significance level based on the student's t-test using MATLAB.

Now, I used ttest function in MATLAB like in the following:

h = ttest(temp_diff,[],'Alpha',0.01)
But, h is coming as a vector of 1×231 (note that temp_diff has dimensions of 152×231, so 231 corresponds to latitude dimension). But, it should come as a 2D matrix with dimension same as temp_diff, i.e, 152×231 so that I can give markers on each significant grid points in the contourf spatial map (latitude vs longitude). So, how to do that in MATLAB? Can anyone please guide me in this regard? That will be very helpful for me. Thank you for your time and consideration.
With regards,
Ankan

Comment: You cannot apply a t-test to a single number. You need multiple measurements to decide if their mean is statistically different from 0 or not. This is why `ttest` works on columns, it does the statistics on the set of numbers in each column.

Comment: Thank you @CrisLuengo for your response. So, if I want to find the grid points where the temperature differences are statistically significant at 95% significance level based on the student's t-test using MATLAB, then should I take two temperature mean value from the two experiments (which are used to compute temperature differences) like in the following: [h,p]=ttest2(temperature1_mean,temperature2_mean)?

Comment: You cannot do what you want to do. The t-test uses multiple measurements to estimate the error in the mean. You have only one measurement per grid point, so you can't do those statistics. What you can do is estimate the error in your measurements in another way, maybe by knowing the device with which you've done the measurements. Or you can take multiple measurements.